# Gradle error when build, failed to calculate

Tags: android, gradle, javac

I debug my app and found this error:

> **1.**  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException:
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
> property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
>
> **2.** Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File task
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property
> 'annotationProcessorSourcesDirectory'
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@57cd73ff)
> before task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not
> supported

Comment: Same issue. Full log here: https://pastebin.com/raw/T3nZexRN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

It is because of the Gradle build version. I had 3.8.0 and it was messing it up, switch to 4.2.0 instead.

In your build.gradle:

- **buildscript-> dependencies-> classpath**

Like this:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)